# the order of application of Sanitization, Escaping and Validation in php

Tags: php

I’m a beginner and trying to create a user registration form in php. After so much searching and reading (mostly here in stack overflow-the search was so intense - twice they asked me if I’m a robot) I came to know that I have to go through at least three (as far as I know) procedures before inserting the data in to the data base.

1.Sanitization
2.Escaping
3.Validation

My question is, what is the order of application of these procedures – which comes first and which one comes second and third.
For example I found this code online.

```
<?php
$emailErr = "";
$email = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
      }
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>
```

They trim, remove back slashes and then replacing the html special characters before validate it with filter_var().
But I think the filter_var() should be the first to apply, is that right or I’m a stupid who doesn’t get it right ?
(By the way – as far as I know the backslashes are allowed in an email, if we use stripslashes() wouldn’t that be a problem too?)

Comment: I've never seen an email with backslashes. Plus the order doesn't matter as long as you get the final result you want.

Comment: @tek please read [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address)

Comment: geez, I'm glad I don't write email validators, thank goodness for email library validators